# fade in and fade out ? Jquery

Tags: jquery

there are 3 div and a img tag in the webform , whenever we clicked on a div the last image's value must fade out , and a new picture fades in .
for example :

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#d2").click(function () {
             $("#img1").fadeToggle();
            document.getElementById("img1").src = "1.jpg";
            $("#img1").fadeIn('fast');
        });

        $("#d3").click(function () {
           $("#img1").fadeToggle();
            document.getElementById("img1").src = "2.jpg";
            $("#img1").fadeIn('fast');
        });

        $("#d4").click(function () {
             $("#img1").fadeToggle();
            document.getElementById("img1").src = "3.jpg";
            $("#img1").fadeIn('fast');
        });
    });
</script>
```

it's wrong ! 
please help me with this !

Comment: share HTML code so we can give you better alternatives..

Comment: You always fadeIn img1? You should change those $("#img1").fadeIn with the number before #d

Answer (score 0):

[The issue](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gnQgD/2/) seems to be the asynchronous nature of `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` methods

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#d2").click(function () {
        $("#img1").stop(true, true).fadeOut(function(){
            this.src = "http://placehold.it/32/ff0000";
            $(this).fadeIn('fast');
        });
    });

    $("#d3").click(function () {
        $("#img1").stop(true, true).fadeOut(function(){
            this.src = "http://placehold.it/32/ffff00";
            $(this).fadeIn('fast');
        });
    });

    $("#d4").click(function () {
        $("#img1").stop(true, true).fadeOut(function(){
            this.src = "http://placehold.it/32/000000";
            $(this).fadeIn('fast');
        });
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/gnQgD/)

**How would I have done it**, Add a class called `img-toggle` and an attribute `data-img` to the `d1`, `d2` and `d3` elements like

```
<div id="d4" class="img-toggle" data-img="http://placehold.it/32/000000">Test</div>
```

then

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".img-toggle").click(function () {
        var src = $(this).data('img')
        $("#img1").stop(true, true).fadeOut(function(){
            this.src = src;
            $(this).fadeIn('fast');
        });
    });
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/XRpLA/)

Answer (score 0):

Not to limit it with only 3 pictures, you can add a class to all those divs for example clickdiv. And then you can continue like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

   $(".clickdiv").click(function(){

     var i=$(this).index();
     $("#img1").fadeToggle();
     document.getElementById("img1").src = (i-1)+".jpg";
    $("#img1").fadeIn('fast');

   });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//Include jQuery first....
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#Id1").click(function () {
        $("#img1").stop(true, true).fadeOut(function(){
            this.src = "put you new displaying image url";
            $(this).fadeIn(); //
        });
    });
});
</script>
```